# What is the best lineup given a table of win percentages

Tags: probability, game-theory

Lets assume you have n decks in a random card game and they are seperated in m factions. For a concrete case, there are 5 factions. You are also given an nxn probability table of the chance of winning of each deck when pitted against another deck. What is the best lineup of the bunch in a best of 5 conquest format, where you can only pick at most one deck per faction? The situation is a tournament with perfect information regarding what decks the opponent will play when the tournament starts, but hidden before it starts.

http://liquipedia.net/hearthstone/Conquest

This means that I will pick 4 decks and my opponent will ban 1.

The best average winrate doesn't necessarily mean that lineup is the best. Targeting possibilities for the top decks can exist.

Comment: You have to define the competition.  If it is round robin your table will tell you everything you need.  It the ranking just based on total wins or do point counts matter?

Comment: That is not enough information.  You would also need to know the relative frequency that each opposing deck appears (*something commonly referred to as the 'Metagame'*).  Once you know that information, then you could run more explicit calculations to get the probability of winning a random match against a random opponent.

Comment: For example, in a game like Hearthstone, if highly aggressive decks become overly common and popular to play, then greedy control decks will perform better as they can stall the game.  If greedy control decks become overly popular to play, then combo-oriented OTKO decks will perform better, and if combo decks become overly popular then aggressive decks perform better so as to not allow the combo decks the chance to draw their combos.  The metagame is generally constantly in flux, not only based on time, but based on ranking as well.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-sum_game#Solution

Comment: I hope i clarified the question even more.